# Redirecting old url to new url on Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Do I need to edit the .htaccess or can I do this via routes.php? How would I redirect a old url to a new url?

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /u/photo.php?id=12345 to /photo/12345
```

I'm currently using /u/username and photo.php?id=$ is acting as a user and not redirecting.

Thank you.

Comment: You should clarify, what URL you want to see in the browser and whether or not you are trying to do clean/pretty URLs or you really want a Redirect e.g . `301`.

Comment: You should be able to do this through routes . I'm 99% sure. I cant send you an answer now but I'll try to post one later when I have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/photo/(.*)$ /u/photo.php?id=$1 [L]
```